# Почему GC (сборщик мусора) убивает объекты приложения, которые на данный момент используются?

Tags: java, android, сборщик-мусора

Столкнулся с проблемой, в моём приложении сборщик мусора убивает объект, который используется для коннекта моего приложения с девайсом по bluetooth, вследствие чего девайс отваливается:

> I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24611(1832KB)
>   AllocSpace objects, 23(428KB) LOS objects, 36% free, 28MB/44MB, paused
>   946us total 109.203ms
>
> W/System.err: java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1
>   W/System.err: at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:495)

Вопрос, почему GC убивает объекты, которые нужны для работы в данный момент времени и вероятно, на них есть ссылка? Можно ли как-то задать приоритет или ещё что-то, какие объекты GC трогать ни в коем случае нельзя?

Comment: Если Вы хотите, что бы GC не уничтожал объекты - сделайте на них ссылку. Либо переходите на нативную сторону разработки - используйте ndk.

А GC уничтожает, потому что нет ссылок.

Comment: А почему вы думаете что это GC что-то не то делает?

Comment: Я смотрю по логу приложения через Android Studio, я вижу, когда проскакивает лог о котором я упомянул выше I/art: Explicit... сразу отваливается bluetooth и высвобождается память, занимаемая приложением

Comment: Так же я не понимаю, как может пропасть ссылка на объект связанный с работой bluetooth, если девайс на данный момент подключен к приложению и функционирует

Comment: То, что девайс подключен, не значит, что на объекты, которые заведуют соединением есть ссылки.

Comment: Странно, KoVadim может быть посоветуете, как действовать в этой ситуации? Так ведь не должно быть, как тогда держать коннект девайса без отвалов?

Comment: Вы же где то создаете это подключение? И у Вас есть объект, который идентифицирует это подключение? сохраняйте его в таком месте, где ссылка будет жить достаточно долго. К примеру, если сохранить в классе, который заведует активити, то как только активити закроют, оно также отвалится (в общем случае).

Comment: Если не можете отследить время жизни объекта, сделайте его статичным. Когда подключение не требуется - просто зануляйте ссылку.

Comment: Сделал объект, который создаёт подключение к девайсу static. Также ранее он был boolean, сейчас я сделал его типа Object. Девайс отваливается теперь не так часто, но всё равно GC чистит этот объект...Может быть попробовать создавать данный объект в классе не являющемся активностью? Или это не имеет значения, т.к. данная активность не уничтожается по жизненному циклу, а только переходит в состояние onPause.

Comment: Или, возможно, попытаться организовать коннект с девайсом в отдельном потоке-демоне или вообще в сервисе